# Check if every field on a string is in another string

Tags: c#, string

I need to compare some strings, and check if every field, separated by spaces, from a string can be found at the other string.
Some fields can be absent on string A, but in any case the fields would be in the same order

Example:

```
String A: AAA CCC DDD    
String B: AAA BBB CCC DDD
```

Ok

```
String A: AAA CCC DDD    
String B: AAA BBB DDD
```

Not Ok

I will use C#, but a generic algorithm would be fine too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both strings on white space and then use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if you get any elements which don't match.

```
if(stringA.Split().Except(stringB.Split()).Any())
{
  //extra elements present
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? It checks that each section in the source string is in the string to compare to.

```
var sourceString = "AAA CCC DDD";
var compareTo = "AAA BBB CCC DDD";

sourceString.Split(' ').All(x=>compareTo.Contains(x));
```

Comment: This one may give false positives, e.g. for `A` and `AA` you should return `false`, but your method will return `true` because `A` is a substring of `AA`.

Comment: Well spotted my fault